# Radio button on click, seeting a default value in the listbox

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 radio buttons(values: Y, N and None) and a list box. 
The default selections on the list box should change depending on which radio button the user selects. If the user clicks the 'Y' radio button, then the list box should default to "XYZ" and so on.

I can't use Jquery.  I have to stick to JS.  Please help me set a default value.

```
function radio4_onclick(ctrl) {
    var flag1;
    for (var i=0; i < 3; i++)
        if (document.form_r1.radio4[i].checked==true)
            flag1= document.form_r1.radio4[i].value;
        if (flag1=='NONE');
        //this is the place where I want to set listbox1 to Default 
}
```

Comment: Can we see your HTML, too?

Comment: Thanks for response, I use WebFocus(BI tool) inbuilt tool to develop HTML pages. By default the tool spits out a lot of Webfocus Internal code. Will try to clean up as much as possible and will post the HTML code

Comment: If its too time-consuming, don't worry about it. Do you need to set the list's default value or just change which option is selected in the list?

Comment: I need to just change the option selected..... When radio button is clicked I want the very first value to be highlighed/Selected.

Answer (score 1):

The first option in a list is selected by default. (See first list in my jfiddle.)
However, you can set the "selectedIndex" of a list like this:

```
var list=document.getElementById('list');
list.selectedIndex = 1;
```

The indexes start at 0. So, if you want the second option, the index is 1, etc.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/AmR8C/1/

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Consider up-voting if you found the answer particularly helpful.